# I want to delete some inserts from the detail table and also the excisting Person in the master table

Tags: mysql, sql-delete, procedure

I got a procedure for a details table, where I delete patient records without appointments (`termin` table). But now I want to delete rows from the master table (`patient`).

I tried it with joins but it doesnt work

```
 DELIMITER $$
 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS  delete_patients $$
 CREATE PROCEDURE delete_patients ()
 BEGIN
  DECLARE v_patient_id INT(6); -- Variable für: ID des aktuellen Patienten
 DECLARE v_patient_number INT(64); -- Variable für: Anzahl der Termine des aktuellen Patienten
 DECLARE exit_loop BOOLEAN; -- Status, zeigt an ob alle Datensätze durchlaufen wurden
 DECLARE select_cursor CURSOR FOR
                        SELECT patient_id
                        FROM patient; -- Holt alle Datensätze (Alle Patienten)
 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET exit_loop = TRUE; -- Der Handler setzt den Status, wenn alle Datensätze (patienten) durchlaufen wurden.
 OPEN select_cursor; -- Öffnet die Datensätze
 select_loop: LOOP -- Startet den Durchlauf aller Datensätze
 FETCH select_cursor INTO v_patient_id; -- Holt immer einen Datensatz (Patienten) und speichert die ID in v_patient_id 
 IF exit_loop THEN -- Gibt es kein Datensatz mehr, wird der Durchlauf beendet.
     CLOSE select_cursor;
     LEAVE select_loop;
 END IF;
    SELECT count(patient_id) INTO v_patient_number FROM termin WHERE patient_id = v_patient_id; -- Zählt die Termine und speichert die Anzahl in v_patient_number 
    IF v_patient_number = 0 THEN -- Sollte v_patient_id gleich 0 sein, also der Patient hat 0 Termine
        DELETE FROM patient WHERE patient_id = v_patient_id; -- Der Patient wurd gelöscht
    END IF;
END LOOP select_loop; -- Ende des Durchlaufs
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Is DELETION a legal requirement? If not, don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

To find patients without appointments you can use

```
select p.*
from patient p
left join termin t on t.patient_id = p.patient_id
where t.patient_id is null
```

[db-fiddle demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eAaSfPcJYMfQzpjMguoB2P/0)

This can be converted to a DELETE statement:

```
delete p
from patient p
left join termin t on t.patient_id = p.patient_id
where t.patient_id is null
```

[db-fiddle demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jyGxf8PPjrGVWBQG2WUjwX/0)

An equivalent query could also be:

```
delete p
from patient p
where not exists (
  select *
  from termin t
  where t.patient_id = p.patient_id
)
```

[db-fiddle demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/79ChfLYU9uaGt9C4DYQBLc/0)

You can use it inside your procedure, but there is not really a need for a procedure at all.